# Object iteration syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

having the below array of objects:

```
obj = [
  column:
    label: "Name"
    value: "name"
  operator:
    label: "Greater than"
    value: "_greater_than"
  input_value: "foo"
  ... ]
```

I can then construct another object to use as URL param like so:

```
query = {}
angular.forEach(obj, (k, v) -> 
  query = ["c[" + k.column.value + k.operator.value + "]=" + k.input_value]
)
```

this returns something like this:

> ["c[name_greater_than]=foo"]

although this does what is meant to do I feel this code is a bit (very?) dirty, so is there a way of making this line more elegant or efficient?

```
query = ["c[" + k.column.value + k.operator.value + "]=" + k.value]
```

Comment: That's not JSON, JSON is a *string* format that can encode JavaScript objects into strings.

Comment: What is `angular.forEach` doing there? Is `obj` actually an array of such objects?

Comment: @Bergi yup obj is an array of objects similar to obj, apologies

Comment: @Jax700303: Then please [edit] your question to include the `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) call doesn't make sense for two reasons:

1. `obj` is only shown to be a single object so there's nothing to iterator over.
2. `angular.forEach` passes the callback the value before the key when iterating over an object but your arguments are `(k, v)`.

Based on that, I'm guessing that `obj` is actually an array of objects that look like the `obj` at the top of your question.

In that case, you could use a simple loop:

```
query = { }
for e in objs
  query["#{e.column.value}#{e.operator.value}"] = e.value
```

Or if the `query = { }` offends you, use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
query = objs.reduce(
  (q, e) -> q["#{e.column.value}#{e.operator.value}"] = e.value; q
  { }
)
```

You might want to write it like this:

```
query = objs.reduce(
  (q, e) ->
    q["#{e.column.value}#{e.operator.value}"] = e.value
    q
  { }
)
```

if you're not used to the paying careful attention to the `reduce` callback's return value.

Comment: Certainly like the first option you present in your answer, apologies for not being clear enough in describing the array (question has been updated to reflect this), your solution is both elegant and efficient, cheers.